# Given an inverse sequence of functors determined on a subcategory, when is the limit determined on that subcategory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, noetherian, limits-colimits

I will first state the general version of my question, but I do have a specific context in mind in which second I'll dance around.

(1.) Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a full subcategory of a category $\mathsf{D}$. Suppose $\{F_{m}\colon\mathsf{D}\to\mathsf{Set}\mid m\in\mathbf{N}\}$ is an inverse system of functors. Write $\lim_{m}F_{m}$ for the limit of $F_{m}$ taken in the category $\mathsf{D}$.

> Suppose for every $m$, $F_{m}$ is determined by its values taken on inputs from $\mathsf{C}$. What conditions are necessary to ensure that $\lim_{m}F_{m}$ is determined by $\mathsf{C}$? Does this property have a name?

(2.) In my specific context, fix a commutative ring $R$ and let $\mathsf{D}=\mathsf{Alg}_{R}$ be the category of $R$-algebras. Let $\mathsf{C}=\mathsf{Noeth}_{R}$ be the full subcategory of noetherian $R$-algebras. It is known that if $Y$ is a locally noetherian scheme, that the functor of points $h_{Y}\colon\mathsf{Alg}_{R}\to\mathsf{Set}$, $h_{Y}(A):=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}_{R}}(\mathrm{Spec}A,Y)$, is determined by noetherian algebras $A$. (See Eisenbud-Harris' *The Geometry of Schemes* Exer. VI-3.) In general, if $\{X_{m}\mid m\in\mathbf{N}\}$ is an inverse system of $R$-schemes, then $\lim_{m}h_{X_{m}}$ is not necessarily representable, because the category $\mathsf{Sch}_{R}$ is not complete.

> However, is it still the case that the functor $\lim_{m}h_{X_{m}}\colon\mathsf{Alg}_{R}\to\mathsf{Set}$ is determined by its values on noetherian $R$-algebras?

Comment: What do you mean by "determined"?

Comment: @FShrike I believe "$F_{m}$ is determined by its values on $\mathsf{C}$" to mean "If $G$ is another functor with $F_{m}(X)\cong G(X)$ for all $X$ in $\mathsf{C}$, then $G\cong F_{m}$ as functors on all of $\mathsf{D}$." That's how I understood Eisenbud-Harris to mean "$h_{Y}$ is determined by noetherian algebras," but please let me know if I'm misunderstanding their statement!

Comment: This sounds right -- but note that the isomorphism $F(X) \cong G(X)$ should be a *natural* iso of the restrictions of $F$ and $G$ to $\mathsf{C}$. I assume this is what you meant; just wanted to clarify for future readers.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what Eisenbud and Harris mean. I think that they just mean that if $h_X$ and $h_Y$ are functors of points for two locally Noetherian schemes $X$ and $Y$, and if $h_X$ and $h_Y$ are isomorphic on restriction to Noetherian algebras, then they are isomorphic. I would imagine it's always possible to come up with a functor $F:\mathsf{Alg}_{R}\to\mathsf{Set}$ that is not the functor of points for any scheme, with $F$ isomorphic to $h_X$ on restriction to Noetherian algebras.

Comment: I think the answer to question (1.) is "yes", but for silly reasons that have nothing to do with limits. I won't post this as an answer just yet, as I don't think it answers anything you actually want to know. But I think it's true that a functor $F:\mathsf{D}\to\mathsf{Set}$ is determined (up to isomorphism) by its restriction to $\mathsf{C}$  iff every object of $\mathsf{D}$ is a retract of an object of $\mathsf{C}$, and the question is completely independent of *which* functor $F$.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask something like "If $F$ and $G$ are limits (indexed by $\mathbf{N}$?) of functors of points, such that $F$ and $G$ are isomorphic on restriction to the subcategory of Noetherian algebras, then are $F$ and $G$ isomorphic?"?